# How to reference a set of files in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xslt, glob

I have a set of files called `x1.xml`, `x2.xml` up to about `x50000.xml`.

I want to search all those files for a string eg. `foo` and return the set of filenames whose file contains the string `foo` eg.;

```
<file>x12.xml<file>
<file>x511.xml<file>
```

I could pass a list of all the filenames into the XSLT and access each file individually using `document($uri)`, but is there some `glob`-like functionality in XSLT 1.0 where I can specify a pattern eg. `document('x*.xml')`?  Or is there some other way?

**Edit...**

I'm using PHP's XSL 1.0 processor `libxslt`.

Comment: In **XSLT 2.0** you can use the `collection()` function http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-collection, but libxslt is a 1.0 processor

Comment: XSLT is probably the wrong tool for this, but from your description so far it's hard to tell. It _sounds_ like you want to scan a directory and _create_ an XML file containing the names of files matching some pattern.  That is much easier done outside of XSLT.

Comment: You could easily generate an XML file with Entity references for each of the individual files that would get expanded and "read" by an XML parser as one giant XML file, and then run an XSLT against the "master XML file" that would include the content from all of the referenced XML files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate an XML file with [**external entity**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-external-ent) references for the individual XML files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
    <!ENTITY fileContent1 SYSTEM "x1.xml">
    <!ENTITY fileContent2 SYSTEM "x2.xml">
    <!ENTITY fileContent3 SYSTEM "x2.xml">
]>
<doc>
    <file name="x1.xml">
        &fileContent1;
    </file>
    <file name="x2.xml">
        &fileContent2;
    </file>
    <file name="x3.xml">
        &fileContent3;
    </file>
</doc>
```

And then transform the XML file, which would contain all of the content of the XML files referenced by the external entity references.

A stylesheet such as the one below when executed against an XML instance like the one above would produce a comma separated list of all the filenames that contain "foo":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:param name="find-value" select="'foo'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="doc/file[contains(., $find-value)]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="file">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Wow that's interesting. It worked a treat, thanks Mads. For anyone like me who's using `PHP`'s `XSL` processor `libxslt`, you must tell the processor to [resolve external entities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php#63764).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use JavaScript of VBScript in your XSLT files. Different XSLT processors support different scripting languages.
Here is one example that shows how to incorporate user defined [VBScript functions in XSL/T](http://manual.altova.com/altovaxml/altovaxmlreporting/index.html?xextmsxsl.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm using PHP's `libxslt`.

Comment: I am not familiar with this library but I am sure it has a similar feature